# git add * does not add deleted files

Tags: git, github

I have a local directory in which I have initialized git. I have added all files of that directory in git using:

```
git add *
```

Now if I delete a file manually from my local directory, I want to get it deleted from github too. I have tried

```
git add -A *
```

But it does not work. Everytime I have to delete it manually from github too.

Comment: I have no problem doing what you are trying. For me the `git add -A` or `git add -A *` (or `git add --all`, which is the same command) all detect the removed file. Can you show more information. (and show your git version) can you do a git status before and after you delete your file and after you do the `git add -A` command? so we can see what happens?

Comment: what is the function of git status? It works after using git status. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Got it. git status lists all files ready to be committed, which have been added to staging, and files not currently being tracked by Git. Use this command to view the state of your working directory and staging area.

Comment: git status is perhaps one of the most useful commands entered as `git status` - it tells you what, well... the status is : )  ... for example if you do a `git add *` and 3 files are added, then you do `git status` it will list the three added files....

Answer (score 22):

The problem is that the glob (`*`) is expanded by your shell, not git, and the shell does not know anything about the files that you have already deleted. `git add -A` without any more arguments would add all the files, including deleted files. `git add .` will also do this in the current git version. You could also use `git rm --cached <file>` for individual files as suggested in other answers.

It's usually easier to just use `git rm` to remove the files, as this will both remove the file AND stage the removal.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the "git rm" command. 
git rm /path/to/file

ex: go to your git directory and type 
git rm file.txt

Then do a git commit say: 
git commit -m "Removing file"

Finally push your changes to your git repository. The file will now be removed from your repository too once you push these changes.

This earlier post on stack overflow gives more information:
[Git: why the file deletion does not sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411272/git-why-the-file-deletion-does-not-sync)

Hope this helps!

Comment: More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411272/git-why-the-file-deletion-does-not-sync

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a file from your index you should use

```
git rm filename
```

Documentation can be found here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm

An important note for this command is:

> git rm will not remove a file from just your working directory. (There is no option to remove a file only from the working tree and yet keep it in the index; use /bin/rm if you want to do that.)

Let me know if it works!

Comment: I know this. Actually I want a command that will synchronize my local directory with git. As  git add -A *      synchronize github with git with both deleted and added files and directories.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to do is when removing files from local repository, rather than **manually deleting** the file from the local repository use,

```
git rm <file-name>
```

or

```
git rm -rf <folder-name>
```

After that, commit the change locally and push it. It should reflect in both local and remote repository.

---

Or if you **have already** manually deleted the files in the local repository and now if you want to remove from the remote repository as well, use `--cached` attribute. That is,

```
git rm --cached <file-name>
```

or

```
git rm -rf --cached <folder-name>
```

---

Now if you **have manually deleted** files and want that reflect in both local and remote git repository, use,

```
git add -u .
```

---

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You are not getting this. I want to delete files from local directory manually. And then sync git with local repo. I don't want to delete every file manually in git too. Is there any such way?

Comment: @NurImtiazulHaque Try, `git add -u .` This should solve what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks it helps. But as I knew        git add -A              does both.

Comment: @NurImtiazulHaque Yes, it does. It depends. To know more about it, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add

Answer (score 0):

I always use `git add -A .` for most everything.

Note the `.` designating your current directory. This adds any changes including all deleted files that are in that directory or underneath it - but not in parent directories (this has bitten me a couple of times).

Just adding this to an old answer because I don't see it suggested.